# Infinite loop :

Tags: java

```
public class Multiply {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int M[][]=new int [3][3];
        int M1[][]=new int[3][3];

        int B=0;
        //int B[][]=new int [3][3];
        //Multiply Matrix 1 by Matrix 2
        //Matrix 1
        //Matrix 2
        //Multiplication
        {
            for(int l=0;l<3;l++)
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                    {
                        for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
                        {   
                            B=(M[i][j]*M1[k][l])+B;

                            while(i==2)
                            {
                                System.out.print(B+" ");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

My program is running into an infinite loop , can someone please tell me where I made a mistake . 
This program multiples two matrices.

Comment: You have more closing braces than opening braces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
while(i==2)
        {
    System.out.print(B+" ");
      }
```

This loop once started, will never finish as the value of the `i` variable is never changed inside the above loop.

Comment: What if I change it to while(j==2) ?

Comment: @TanyaRao It will happens the same. Do you know what is the purpose of a while ? If j = 2 you will enter in your will loop. Since you're not increasing it, the program will again read the instruction j==2 and evaluate it to true. So you will have an infinite loop too.

Comment: Same thing if you change it to `while (j == 2)`. You sould change this to `if (i == 2)`.

Comment: Will result in the same. What do you want to achive? Print the value of the computed `M` variable? Then add `System.out.print` to the loop where the `M` variable is computed.

Comment: @Tanya Rao Adam already asnwered to your question . it is the same if you not change j inside it the same will happen

Comment: Thanks everyone . I understood my mistake and also the functionality of the while loop .

Answer (score 3):

while loop not terminates. Hence do a

```
if(i==2){

 System.out.print(B+" ")

}
```

Comment: Thank you , I understood why the while loop was running into an infinite loop .

Comment: @TanyaRao you are welcome. Nice to hear you got it.